# How to make line number colored in python logging?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I'd like to make the line numbers of the logger statement colored. As far as I've found out, I have to write a complete new code for that [1]. Is there any shorter way to make lines of following logger colored? i.e change the `%(lineno)d'` part so Terminal would have colors in line numbers. Thanks.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
       format='%(name)-12s %(funcName)s() %(message)s %(lineno)d')  
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

[1] [Python Colorlog not printing in the log files with colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959077/python-colorlog-not-printing-in-the-log-files-with-colors)

Comment: I think you should look again at the answer to the question you refer to. It explains how the colours are achieved and why it is a *bad idea* to put the required non-printing characters into logfiles. You would to do better to write a simple Python program that reads the logfile  and colorizes the line numbers as they are sent to the terminal.

Comment: What the previous comment states (it may be OK to use for screen output, but would not put color information in a log file). But also coloring output depends on your terminal. Esp. difference between native windows and U*X system with ANSI control codes support is rather substantial. You can have a look for instance at [colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama).